# How do I load an Angularjs app inside an ajax app?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, angularjs

I'm trying to load part of an angularjs app inside an ajax page, i've made it work with controllers but having a hard time with angularjs apps with modules

Page

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#bt").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost/ajax/ng.php?p=1",
                success: function( data ) {
                    $("#game").html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="bt" value="poker"></input>

<div id="game">

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

php

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET["p"])){
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        //echo "<script src=\"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js\"></script><div ng-app=\"myApp\"><h1 ng-controller='MainCtrl'>{{text}}</h1></div>";
        echo "<div ng-app><h1 ng-controller='MainCtrl'>{{text}}</h1></div><script src=\"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js\"></script><script src=\"http://localhost/ajax/app.js\">";
    }

?>
```

JS file

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
$scope.text = 'Hello, Angular fanatic.';
}]);
```

whenever i try to declare a module name in my div it does not load angular and shows only the {{text}}

Comment: I am not a downvoter but your question is not clear. `i've made it work with controllers` can you post that too or create a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ for that. In which part do you need help from us?

Comment: nobody can help you with this much info , add some code or more details .

Comment: sorry dudes first time asking^^

Answer (score 1):

You are not bootstrapping the dynamicly added html code. Don't use ng-app, use

```
angular.bootstrap(element,["module"]
```

`angular.bootstrap` must be called after you add the html to the element. Also, why are you not declaring the ng-app on the entire document  and using ng-include or ngRoute to load dynamic sections?